# Trying to merge columns from multiple csv's, but the merged dataframe is coming up NULL

Tags: r, merge, lapply, rbind, do.call

My problem seems to be two-fold. I am using code that has worked before. I re-ran my scripts and got similar outputs, but saved to a new location. I have changed all of my setwd lines accordingly. But, there may be an error with either setwd or the do.call function.

In R, I want to merge 25 csv's that are located in a folder- only certain columns

My path is 
    /Documents/CODE/merge_file/2sp

So, I do:
    setwd("/Documents/CODE")
but then I get an error saying cannot change working directory (usually works fine). So then I manually set working directory in the Session in RStudio.

The next script seems to run fine:

```
myMergedData2 <- 
  do.call(rbind,
          lapply(list.files(path = "/Documents/CODE/merge_file/2sp"), 
read.csv))
```

myMergedData2 ends up in the global environment, but it says it is NULL (empty), though the console makes it look like everything is ok.

I would then like to save just these columns of information but I can't even get to this point.
   myMergedData2<-myMergedData2[c(2:5),c(10:12)]

And then add this 
   myMergedData2<-myMergedData2 %>% mutate(richness = 2)%>% select(richness, 
   everything())

And then I would like to save

setwd("/Documents/CODE/merge_file/allsp")
   write.csv(myMergedData2, "/Documents/CODE/merge_file/allsp/2sp.csv")

I am trying to merge these data so I can use ggplot 2 and show how my response variables (columns 2-5) according to my independent variables (columns 10-12). I have 25 different parameter sets with 50 observations in each csv.

Comment: I uninstalled and updated R and reinstalled tidyverse and dplyr and I'm still getting the same errors "cannot change working directory" if I set the working directory in the script and then a NULL, empty object if I run do.call etc after manually setting the working directory from session in Rstudio.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so the issue was that my dropbox didn't have enough space and I weirdly don't have permissions to do what I was trying on my university's H drive. Bizarre, but easy fix with the increase in space on Dropbox to allow for complete syncing of csv's.

Sometimes the issue is minor!